# Zipping the contents of a folders in PHP

Tags: php, file, compression, zip

Before marking this post as a duplicate, please note that I have already searched for answer on SO and the once I've found so far (listed below) haven't been exactly what I've been looking for.

- [How to [recursively] Zip a directory in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php)
- [using zipArchive addFile() will not add image to zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422983/using-ziparchive-addfile-will-not-add-image-to-zip)
- [ZipArchive - addFile won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289456/ziparchive-addfile-wont-work)

Those are just some of the ones I've looked at.

My problem is this: I can't use addFromString, I **have** to use addFile, it's a requirement of the task.

I've already tried a couple of ways, here's my current iteration:

```
public function getZippedFiles($path)
{
    $real_path = WEBROOT_PATH.$path;

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($real_path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

    //# create a temp file & open it
    $tmp_file = tempnam($real_path,'');
    $zip_file = preg_replace('"\.tmp$"', '.zip', $tmp_file);

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach ($files as $name=>$file)
    {
        error_log(print_r($name, true));
        error_log(print_r($file, true));
        if ( ($file == ".") || ($file == "..") )
        {
            continue;
        }

        $file_path = $file->getRealPath();
        $zip->addFile($file_path);
    }

    $zip->close();
}
```

When I try to open the resulting file, I get told that "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed(zipped) Folder '' is invalid."

I've managed to succesfully complete the task using addFromString, like so:

```
$file_path = WEBROOT_PATH.$path;
    $files = array();
    if (is_dir($file_path) == true)
    {
        if ($handle = opendir($file_path))
        {
            while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
            {
                if (is_dir($file_path.$file) == false)
                {
                    $files[] = $file_path."\\".$file;
                }
            }

            //# create new zip opbject
            $zip = new ZipArchive();

            //# create a temp file & open it
            $tmp_file = tempnam($file_path,'');
            $zip_file = preg_replace('"\.tmp$"', '.zip', $tmp_file);

            $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

            //# loop through each file
            foreach($files as $file){

                //# download file
                $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

                //#add it to the zip
                $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);

            }

            //# close zip
            $zip->close();
        }
    }
}
```

The above is mostly just copied straight from some example code I saw somewhere. If anyone can point me in a good direction I'd be very grateful!

***** UPDATE *****
I added an if around the close like this:

```
if (!$zip->close()) {
    echo "failed writing zip to archive";
}
```

The message gets echoed out, so obviously the problem is there. I've also checked to make sure the `$zip->open()` works, and I've confirmed that it is opening it without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get something working using `addFile`.

I created a helper class that contains 3 functions: one to list all the files in a directory, 1 to zip all those files, and 1 to download the zipped files:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/config.php");

class FileHelper extends ZipArchive
{
    /**
     * Lists files in dir
     * 
     * This function expects an absolute path to a folder intended as the target.
     * The function will attempt to create an array containing the full paths to 
     * all files in the target directory, except for . and ..
     * 
     * @param dir [string]    : absolute path to the target directory
     * 
     * @return result [array] : array of absolute paths pointing to files in the target directory
     */
    public static function listDirectory($dir)
    {
        $result = array();
        $root = scandir($dir);
        foreach($root as $value) {
            if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {
                continue;
            }
            if(is_file("$dir$value")) {
                $result[] = "$dir$value";
                continue;
            }
            if(is_dir("$dir$value")) {
                $result[] = "$dir$value/";
            }
            foreach(self::listDirectory("$dir$value/") as $value)
            {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Zips and downloads files
     * 
     * This function expects a directory location as target for a temp file, and a list(array)
     * of absolute file names that will be compressed and added to a zip file. After compression,
     * the temporary zipped file will be downloaded and deleted.
     * 
     * @param location [string] : absolute path to the directory that will contain the temp file
     * @param file_list [array] : array of absolute paths pointing to files that need to be compressed
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function downloadZip($file)
    {
        $modules = apache_get_modules();
        if (in_array('mod_xsendfile', $modules)) // Note, it is not possible to detect if X-SendFile is turned on or not, we can only check if the module is installed. If X-SendFile is installed but turned off, file downloads will not work
        {
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header("X-Sendfile: ".realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).$file);

            // Apache will take care of the rest, so terminate the script
            exit;
        }

        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($file)) );
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Pragma: public");

        ob_end_clean(); // Without this, the file will be read into the output buffer which destroys memory on large files
        readfile($file);
    }

    /**
     * Zips files
     * 
     * This function expects a directory location as target for a temp file, and a list(array)
     * of absolute file names that will be compressed and added to a zip file. 
     * 
     * @param location [string]  : absolute path to the directory that will contain the temp file
     * @param file_list [array]  : array of absolute paths pointing to files that need to be compressed
     * 
     * @return zip_file [string] : absolute file path of the freshly zipped file
     */
    public function zipFile($location, $file_list)
    {
        $tmp_file = tempnam($location,'');
        $zip_file = preg_replace('"\.tmp$"', '.zip', $tmp_file);

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true)
        {
            foreach ($file_list as $file)
            {
                if ($file !== $zip_file)
                {
                    $zip->addFile($file, substr($file, strlen($location)));
                }
            }
            $zip->close();
        }

        // delete the temporary files
        unlink($tmp_file);

        return $zip_file;
    }
}
?>
```

Here's how I called this class's functions:

```
$location = "d:/some/path/to/file/";
$file_list = $file_helper::listDirectory($location);
$zip_file = $file_helper->zipFile($location, $file_list);
$file_helper->downloadZip($zip_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution, much clearer:

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($source . '/', '', $file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($source . '/', '', $file));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}
```

And use it like:

```
Zip('/folder/to/compress/', './compressed.zip');
```

Check the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php) with addFromString

Comment: I'm sure your answer might be a good solution generally, but I can't use it, since `My problem is this: I can't use addFromString, I have to use addFile, it's a requirement of the task.`

I cannot use addFromString, I *have* to use addFile, but I haven't been able to get it working. The only indication of an error is that windows cannot open the zipped file.

Comment: @Skytiger Sorry for not taking care to read the requirement. Can you tell me why is this a requirement? Performance? Client, Boss, Academical? I updated the question with a version using addFile that does the exactly same job

Comment: It's a mixture of my boss's preference and improvement in performance.

I did manage to get a solution working, you can see it in my answer below :)

Comment: @Skytiger yes I did. It's wierd but in my tests zipping the phpmyadmin folder contents with this code, addFromString was faster. Then I tried on a 300mb folder with lots of files and dirs.. again addFromString was faster. Maybe file_get_contents is more optimized than zip addFile internals

Comment: The problem we're going to be facing when this code goes live is that the average filesize of the files that need to be zipped will be in the area of 20gb. As far as I know the addFromString starts to fall behind the addFile method when file sizes get that big.